# Delete Query Taking to Long to Run in Google Cloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform

I have a table with 433,332 records in a MySql Database in Google Cloud.
The Table looks something like this

```
Album_ID | Track_Len | Track_Name                            | Ft_LName1 | Ft_FName1 | Ft_LName2 | Ft_FName2 | Ft_LName3 | Ft_FName3 | Row_Num |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| N40781  |      5.19 | Tumbala (Da Lata Remix)               | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       1 |
| N40781  |      5.01 | Ruperta (Zeb Remix)                   | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       2 |
| N40781  |      6.35 | Coba Guarango (Toni Economides Remix) | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       3 |
| B15033  |      6.02 | II-V-P                                | Quartet   | ARC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       4 |
| N32395  |      4.47 | My Babe                               | Stigers   | Curtis    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       5 |
| N32395  |      5.13 | Thats All Right                       | Stigers   | Curtis    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       6 |
```

Note the Primary key of this table is supposed to be (Album_ID, Track_Name)
I am aware there are duplicate data entries in the table.
I am attempting to run the following query to find and delete these entries:

```
select count(*) 
from Track t1, Track t2 
where t1.Album_ID = t2.Album_ID 
AND t1.Track_Name = t2.Track_Name 
AND t1.Row_Num > t2.Row_Num;
```

However this is taking an extremely long time to run. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of duplicates, I would suggest:

```
select Album_ID, Track_Name, count(*) 
from Track t
group by Album_ID, Track_Name,
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want the count, then:

```
select count(*) as num_keys_with_duplicates,
       sum(cnt - 1) as num_duplicates
from (select Album_ID, Track_Name, count(*) as cnt
      from Track t
      group by Album_ID, Track_Name,
      having count(*) > 1
     ) x;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. What's the purpose of x at the end of the 2nd query?

Comment: @Elkip . . . It is a *table alias*.  Some databases require them for subqueries in the `from` clause.